# How we get the jacobi elliptic functions

Tags: integration, analysis, elliptic-equations, elliptic-integrals

I am encountering an issue with Jacobi elliptic functions. Specifically, I am facing a challenge with the following integral:

$$\pm\int_{-\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\eta}}}^{u}\frac{\mathrm ds}{s\sqrt{\left(s+\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\eta}}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\eta}}-s\right)}}=\sqrt{\frac{\eta}{2}}x$$

I know that the result is

$$u=-\sqrt{\frac{2\mu}{\eta}} \operatorname{sech}(\sqrt{\mu}x) $$

However, the challenge lies in understanding how to derive this result. Despite investing a significant amount of time, I am struggling to comprehend the process leading to this outcome.

Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I edit my text @TedShifrin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$F(u,v)=\int_{-v}^u\frac{\mathrm ds}{s\sqrt{(v-s)(v+s)}}$$
Your integral in question is $F\big(u(x),\sqrt{2\mu/\eta}\big)$. Letting for abbreviation purposes $t=\sqrt{2\mu/\eta}$, the question is to find a function $u(x)$ such that
$$F\big(u(x),t\big)=\sqrt{\eta/2}~x$$
Taking the derivative (wrt $x$) on both sides,
$$(\partial_u F)\big(u(x),t\big)~\cdot u'(x)  =\sqrt{\eta/2}$$

Which boils down to solving the differential equation
$$\frac{u'(x)}{u(x)\sqrt{t-u(x)}\sqrt{t+u(x)}}=\text{constant}$$

The solutions of which are given by some formula involving hyperbolic secant.

Comment: Thanks a lot @K.defaoite, I'm new in this field so where I can find the solution of this kind of differential equations?

Comment: Why not integrate $F(u,v)$ elementarily? (After $s=v\sin t$, say, we get $\int\frac{dt}{\sin t}=\log\left|\tan\frac t2\right|$, etc.)

Comment: @metamorphy I guess that works too. This is just the first thing that sprang to mind.

Comment: @metamorphy thanks a lot, it's a good idea and it's march.